# Update content after selecting item in spinner

Tags: android

its me again. I tried the last hours, how to change content of a spinner.
ok, lets start from the beginning.

I have three spinners. They all have initial values. The first spinner is the main spinner and the other two spinners depend on the vale chosen in the first one. So i want to update the last two spinners after making a selection in spinner one. *edit: All spinners are on the same activity.

How can i achieve this? My problem is that i can only make changes in the spinners onitemselectadapter but thats a whole new class. I cannot reach the activity where my other spinners are.

thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are your spinners in different activities?

If they are, so you can just pass the selected value of the first spinner via [Intent](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Intent.html) (See the putExtra section) and retrieve the value from the next activity so that you can set accordingly the next spinners.

Edit:

Here is an example that changes the selected item in the 2nd and 3rd spinner. Update the listener (onItemSelected method) with your logic

Activity:

```
private Spinner s;
private Spinner s2;
private Spinner s3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String[] myList = new String[] { "Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar" };
    String[] myList2 = new String[] { "Hello2", "World2", "Foo2", "Bar2" };
    String[] myList3 = new String[] { "Hello3", "World3", "Foo3", "Bar3" };

    s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    s3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

    s.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myList));
    s2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myList2));
    s3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myList3));


    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int pos, long id) {
            s2.setSelection(pos);
            s3.setSelection(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


        }});
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi ccheneson, no they are all one the same activity.

Comment: so what do you mean by "My problem is that i can only make changes in the spinners onitemselectadapter but thats a whole new class. I cannot reach the activity where my other spinners are."?

Comment: sry buddy, i was to stupid. You example works like a charm. Thank you.