# onItemSelected property of spinner in android

Tags: java, android

```
Spinner spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> choice1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data1);
    choice1
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    choice2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data2);
    choice2
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

In this code i am creating two drop downs and now my requirement is when i select the item from first combo the data in the second combo must be changed according to the selected item of first combo.

now in onItemSelected property how to code specially for first dropdown?

Comment: See this thread if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262412/update-content-after-selecting-item-in-spinner

Answer (score 0):

Your class (`this`) is a listener for events that are fired, when the selection of one of two spinners changes.

So the class has to implement the interface method which catches those events. Inside this method, you (1) determine *which* spinner fired the event (= has changed) and, if it is spinner 1, (2) get the actual value from spinner 1 and (3) use the value to set spinner 2. This might result in another event which has to be ignored.

**EDIT**

one of the interface methods of `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`is

```
public abstract void  onItemSelected  (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id);
```

The AdapterView (`parent`) which is passed is exactly that object that fired the event, so either `parent == spin1` or `parent == spin2` is true (unless you don't listen to more widgets).

BTW: `spin1` and `spin2` need to be class members because the `onItemSelect` methods needs to access them.

Comment: how to detemine which spinner fired the event?

Comment: within `onItemSelected()` you might be able to test `if (id == R.id.spinner1)` If that doesn't work then `if (view.getId() == R.id.spinner1)` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v,int position, long id) {
 // you decide here based on parent

if (parent==spin1) {
// do something with spin1
}
else if (parent==spin2) {
// do something with spin2
}
}
```