# fields depending on the number given by spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

i am working on spinner regarding medicines,when i select number of  medicines i want to order i am using spinner and if i select 4 in the spinner then i get 4 fields which display each name of the medicine

but i got struck on the fields which will be depending on the spinner number(if i want 4 fields i give number 4 to the spinner and thus i will get 4 fields displayed,and if i want only 3 then i only get 3 fields ) the fields i want to display them so that user can enter the required data

Code:

```
public class SpecficTheMedicines extends ActionBarActivity {
    Toolbar spcifytoolbar;
    Spinner numberdrop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.letmespecify);
        spcifytoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.spcifytoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(spcifytoolbar);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        numberdrop = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.numberdrop);
        ArrayList<String> number = new ArrayList<String>();
        number.add("1");
        number.add("2");
        number.add("3");
        number.add("4");
        number.add("5");
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinneradapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, number);
        spinneradapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        numberdrop.setAdapter(spinneradapter);
showInfo();
    }
    public void showInfo(){
LayoutInflater layoutInfralte=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.infolayout);
List views=new ArrayList();

Iterator<latlng>ite=NavigationContext.getInstance().getArray().iterator();
latlng temp;
while(ite.hasNext()){
    temp=ite.next();
    View view=layoutInfralte.inflate(R.layout.infoitem, null);
    // Edit
    TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextAddress);
    tv.setText(temp.address);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    views.add(view);
}
for(int i = 0; i<views.size(); i++)
    linearLayout.addView((View) views.get(i));
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update content after selecting item in spinner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262412/update-content-after-selecting-item-in-spinner)

Comment: but how can i select the fields means shall i have to inflate them?and i want in the same activity